# Customize tooltip of donut chart in dimple.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I would like that my donut chart tooltip look like this:

[image]

Until now I had tried this code snippet based in http://annapawlicka.com/pretty-charts-with-dimple-js/

```
// Handle the hover event - overriding the default behaviour
s.addEventHandler("mouseover", onHover);
// Handle the leave event - overriding the default behaviour
s.addEventHandler("mouseleave", onLeave);

myChart.draw();

function onHover(e) {
    // Get the properties of the selected shape
    var cx = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("x")),
        cy = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("y"));

    // Set the size and position of the popup
    var width = 150,
        height = 70,
        x = (cx + width + 10 < svg.attr("width") ?
             cx + 10 :
             cx - width - 20);  
        y = (cy - height / 2 < 0 ?
            15 :
            cy - height / 2);

    // Create a group for the popup objects
    popup = svg.append("g");

    // Add a rectangle surrounding the text
    popup
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x",5)
            .attr("y",5)
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 20)
            .attr("rx", 5)
            .attr("ry", 5)
            .style("fill", 'white')
            .style("stroke", 'black')
            .style("stroke-width", 2);


    // Add multiple lines of text
    popup
            .append('text')
            .attr('x', 17)
            .attr('y', 17)
            .text(e.seriesValue[0])
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .style("font-size", 10);
            }

function onLeave(e) {
                // Remove the popup
                if (popup !== null) {
                    popup.remove();
                }
            }
```

I'm having problems getting the position of the selected shape, because this part of the code does not seem to work with donut charts.

```
var cx = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("x")),
    cy = parseFloat(e.selectedShape.attr("y"));
```

Thats why I'm not using cx or cy, because I got NaN. The rest of the code seems to work fine and I can edit the text, text color, background and some other things.

I would like to know how to get the posistion of the hovered shape and if its possible (I guess I'm asking too much...), get the arrow-form (whatever its called) of the rectangle tooltip.

Comment: Seens like the ring chart is broken in the 1.0 version of dimple . http://jsbin.com/konir/1/edit

Comment: My snippet was based on the point tooltip, and I don't recall dimple having pie charts back then :) If you look at the source code of a pie chart, you can see it's using a bar tooltip: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/master/src/methods/_showBarTooltip.js
But it's already been mentioned below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Here](http://jsbin.com/kovat/1/edit)** is the solution using d3 pointed by John.

#### HTML

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

#### JS

```
var path = e.selectedShape[0][0];

var d3path = d3.select(path);

var box = d3path.node().getBBox();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have works, but this option keeps the tool tip styling the same as the piece of the chart your hovering over.  Try this:

```
ring.getTooltipText = function (e) {
    return [
        e.aggField[0]
    ]};
```

Here is your updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/gogeqajegice/3/edit

Comment: ...I guess this doesn't help with positioning or adding the arrow

Comment: This tutorial has some great info on custom tooltips using Dimple.js http://annapawlicka.com/pretty-charts-with-dimple-js/